# Two-way binding Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix <Data> <Variable>

Tags: android, xml

Trying to implement two way binding
As mentioned:

[Data Binding Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html)

[Two-way Android Data Binding - How to use two-way Data Binding to manage a layout](https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/android-data-binding-f9f9d3afc761)

[2-way Data Binding on Android!](https://halfthought.wordpress.com/2016/03/23/2-way-data-binding-on-android/)

However on

```
<variable type="com.example.gideonsassoon.avariel.datamodels.Player" name="name"/>
```

I am getting the following message.:

> "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix less... (Ctrl+F1) 
>   Most Android views have attributes in the Android namespace. When
>   referencing these attributes you must include the namespace prefix, or
>   your attribute will be interpreted by aapt as just a custom attribute.
>   Similarly, in manifest files, nearly all attributes should be in the
>   android: namespace."

If I try to build it puts all the R. in my file in red and state they don't exist etc.

I have edited my build gradle file to have

```
dataBinding.enabled = true
```

Full code up to the point relevant below

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    tools:context="com.example.gideonsassoon.avariel.ui.MainFragmentActivity">
    <data>
        <variable type="com.example.gideonsassoon.avariel.datamodels.Player" name="name"/>
    </data>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/viewpagerStrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_character_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@string/name_colon"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
            android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_character_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:text="@={player.name}"

            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tv_character_name"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tv_character_name"

            android:ems="12"
            android:hint="@string/character_name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Ahh it appears to be that I have it as relativeLayout. It can't be "binding" so it can only be layout. Not sure how that's gonna affect my files as a whole but I guess we'll just have to see how it plays out. Here's my source. However if anyone wants to answer to that effect it would be most appreciated.

[Using data binding in Android - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDatabinding/article.html)